# Store procedure en oracle, select

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure

estoy tratando de generar un SP en oracle el cual me devuelva un select de una columna.

Actualmente

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_usuario(idUser IN USUARIO.ID%TYPE,
  O_EMAIL OUT USUARIO.EMAIL%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT EMAIL
   INTO O_EMAIL
   FROM USUARIO WHERE ID = idUser;
END get_usuario; -- Procedure
```

El problema radica en que `O_EMAIL` solo se cargara con 1 dato, yo necesito devolver el select completo de `email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que utilizar un cursor.  Algo asi:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_usuario(idUser IN USUARIO.ID%TYPE, 
  cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS

BEGIN

OPEN cursor_ FOR
      SELECT EMAIL   
      FROM USUARIO WHERE ID = idUser; 
END;
```

Comment: Perfecto Alan!, acabo de realizar algunas pruebas y esto es correcto!